# the parentheses in str_match change the match

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I am trying to extract the content between two slashed in a url, and for this I am using `stringr` function `str_match`.

```
library(stringr)
test <- "http://www.lefigaro.fr/flash-actu/2014/04/08/97001-20140408FILWWW00162-ump-cope-defend-sa-gestion-financiere.php"
```

I manage to extract the full string:

```
str_match(test, "http://.*?/.*?/")

     [,1]                                
[1,] "http://www.lefigaro.fr/flash-actu/"
```

But when I add the parentheses to extract the match within the string the result changes unexpectedly:

```
str_match(test, "http://.*?/(.*?)/")

     [,1]                                      [,2]  
[1,] "http://www.lefigaro.fr/flash-actu/2014/" "2014"
```

Must be a matter of how the parentheses are interpreted in regex. Any clue?

Comment: seems something wrong with the `stringr` library.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/bD7yR0/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe if you change `(.*?)` by `([^/]*?)` it will work.

- `.` matches any character
- `[^/]` matches all characters that are not a `/`

I'm not used to stringr, but that is what i'd do in php with preg_ functions.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Heru-Luin, your suggestion works on this particular case: `str_match(test, "http://[^/]*?/(.*?)/")` outputs "flash-actu". However, I do not understand the reason of the error, if an error it really is, in the capture group.

Comment: Your regex also captured slashes "/", so it matched "flash-actu", the slash, and one more bit.
Adding "[^/]" forbids the regex to match slashes, so now, it only takes flash-actu :)